# smartref package: Problems when referencing from math mode \text{}

Tags: math-mode, cross-referencing, amsmath

I'm getting errors when using `smartref`'s `\sectionref` command (or similar) from inside `amsmath`'s `\text{...}` environment inside math mode. MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{smartref}

\addtoreflist{section}

% see below for what this is for.
\addtoreflist{subsection}

\begin{document}

\section{Foosec} \label{hello}

% Works:
\sectionref{hello}

% Works:
$\sectionref{hello}$

% Does /not/ work:
%   ! Argument of \@car has an extra }.
% or just hangup, depending on whether \addtoreflist{subsection} above
% is active.
$\text{\sectionref{hello}}$

\end{document}
```

Any ideas?
(my use case is putting explicative references to theorems above equality signs)

Comment: is there a reason that you can't use just `\ref`?  i can provide an example (using `\stackrel` and `\text`) that works with that combination.  (untangling the reason for the failure with `\@car` would require more time than i have available now.)

Comment: Well, in fact I'm not using `\sectionref`, but `\thmref` with amsmath's theorem environments (which produces exactly the same error). I have some theorems with an enumeration inside and I'd like to reference theorems like 4.12.ii or (ii), depending on the context.

I wrote it all up and it works nicely, the only issue left is this one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that neutralizing `\@getsmartref` when `\iffirstchoice@` is false can solve the problem. The command `\text` must build four copies of the same text, one of which will be eventually used. So, in order not to do the wrong thing, it introduces a conditional `\iffirstchoice@` and patches `\addtocounter` so it does nothing when typesetting the final three boxes.

However, `\@getsmartref` relies on changing counters. However, the computation is needed only once, when typesetting the first box; in the other three boxes the needed value is already known.

Thus I surround the code of `\@getsmartref` between `\iffirstchoice@` and `\fi`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{smartref}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\pretocmd{\@getsmartref}{\iffirstchoice@}{}{}
\apptocmd{\@getsmartref}{\fi}{}{}
\makeatother

\addtoreflist{section}
\begin{document}

\section{Foosec}

\begin{equation}
1=1\label{foo}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
a+b=c\label{hello}
\end{equation}

\sectionref{hello}
$\text{\sectionref{hello}}_{\text{\sectionref{hello}}}$

\end{document}
```

---

Suppose you have, for some reason, `$\text{\refstepcounter{foo}something else}$`. If `\text` didn't take precautions, the counter would be stepped four times. Therefore the `amstext` package redefines `\addtocounter` (the macro `\refstepcounter` relies on) in order that it does its work only once.

Unfortunately, `smartref` uses `\addtocounter` rather than lower level commands, for doing its tasks. Using local counters and `\advance` would be much better, in this case.

A better definition of `\@getsmartref` would be

```
\newcount\sr@currsmartlistplace
\newcommand*{\@getsmartref}[3]{%Parameters are: #1: Where #2: Label, #3: place in list
    \edef\@smartlistplace{#3}%
    \sr@currsmartlistplace=\z@
    \edef\@originalsmartlist{%
        \expandafter\@getsmartreflist\csname sr@#2\endcsname{}{}}%
    \edef\@currsmartlist{\@originalsmartlist}%
    \loop%
        \edef\@currsmartvalue{\expandafter\@car\@currsmartlist\@nil}%
        \ifnum\sr@currsmartlistplace=\value{less@smartlist}%
            \edef\@currsmartlist{\noexpand{\expandafter\@cdr\@currsmartlist\@nil\noexpand}}%
        \else
            \edef\@currsmartlist{\expandafter\@cdr\@currsmartlist\@nil}%
        \fi
        \ifnum\sr@currsmartlistplace<\@smartlistplace
            \advance\sr@currsmartlistplace\@ne
    \repeat
    \edef#1{\@currsmartvalue}%
%    \typeout{Got Smart Reference (place #3, value \@currsmartvalue)}%
    }
```

which wouldn't need any special treatment when found in `\text`.

Comment: do i interpret this correctly as meaning any modification is best done in `smartref` (if `amsmath` has been loaded)?  i can't see that any change to how `amstext` (automatically included by `amsmath`) would solve the problem.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Yes, it's a problem that `smartref` should solve.

Comment: It just works, very nice, thank you so much! If you don't mind, could you explain why it works? I looked at the source of `smartref` and `\text` in `amsmath`, yet I couldn't figure it out. Why does `\text` have to bother with counters at all? And how could it be a problem for `\@getsmartref` to be evaluated several times?

Comment: @rainmaker I added some other explanations

Comment: Now I got it! So inside `\text{...}` and with `\firstchoice@false`, `\setcounter` won't do anything, which is strongly unexpected by the definition of `\@getsmartref` which assumes `\setcounter` to just set the counter. Hah, thanks!